# How to vertically center a span and a list inside a div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a div fixed to the top of the browser. The div has 100% width and 90px height. Inside is a span of text that should go on the left and a horizontal list that should go to the right. Right now I am floating the span to the left and the list to the right. How can I vertically center the span and the list within the div?

http://jsfiddle.net/4keeS/6/

Comment: There's a good breakdown of vertical centering techniques in this article, I haven't used any except the child-of-known-height technique in my answer below: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution ...

http://jsfiddle.net/4keeS/7/

... using this on the span and li

```
display:inline-block;
line-height:70px;
height: 70px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, vertical alignment is only applicable for table cells (i.e.: `TD` and `TH` elements).
So you'll have to use `TABLE` in order to align contents vertically.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .text         { float: left; }
    .list         { list-style: none; float: right; margin: 0; }
    .list li      { float: left; }
    #vdivwrap     { width: 100%; }
    #vdivcontent  { height:90px; vertical-align: center; background:#8c8; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="vdivwrap" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <td id="vdivcontent">
      <span class="text">[text span]</span>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>[list item 1]</li>
        <li>[list item 2]</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of your title span & UL content, you can do it with

```
position:absolute /* or relative */;
top:50%;
margin-top: -X /* where X is half the height of your content. That's a negative margin pulling the content up so it's center aligns with the center of the parent div */;
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XAgyv/1/

I haven't found any good ways to do this without knowing the height of content to be vertically centered- I look forward to seeing other answers.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to add another css rule as following

```
span, ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

here is working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/logiccanvas/4keeS/9/